# Win32 CreateProcess; Inheriting System Environment. The final piece of the puzzle

Tags: c++, winapi, environment

Dear my stack overflow comrades. I have a question. I cannot find the answer via google. Thus I have no other alternative.

But first, once upon a time I was a GUI dunce, until I met upon fam trinli videos on game making in SFML. Through his source code I discovered and ventured deep into the Win32 universe and discovered CreateProcess. Since then CreateProcess has been a pain in the neck!

Fast forward to today. I am still married to Cpp, and thus obliged to use CreateProcess for my latest work which is connecting to MariaDb Server.

I thought I could solve my problem, with my little function wrapper around CreateProcess, but was a struck problem. ReadFile deadlocks, and stuff. I decided to just make a Process class and abstract away every functionality of CreateProcess. Have a look...

```
class Process
{
 public:
    enum { INVALID_EXIT_CODE = -1, };
    enum { AUTO_KILL=1, WAIT=2, DEBUG=4, };

    struct Builder
    {
     //to allow easy building of sorted environmment strings
     using EnvList = std::map <std::string,std::istringstream>;

     istringstream cmd;
     EnvList env_list; 
     Jav::cstring app_name;
     Jav::cstring current_dir;
     STARTUPINFOA si;
    };

 public:
    Process(const char *cmd=NULL,const char *current_dir=NULL,const char *app_name=NULL);
    ~Process ();

 public:
    bool launch();
    int stop();
    int wait(uint time=INFINITE);
    
    size_t read (void*,size_t);
    size_t readError(void*,size_t);
    size_t write(const void*,size_t);
    size_t write(const char*);

    size_t read_async(void*,size_t);
    size_t readError_async(void*,size_t);
    size_t write_async(const void*,size_t);
    size_t write_async(const char*);

    void setAppName(const char*);
    void setCurrentDir(const char*);
    void addArg(const char*);
    void addEnv(const char *var,const char *val);

    void setConsoleTitle(const char*);
    void setConsoleWidth(int);
    void setConsoleHeight(int);
    void setConsoleTextAndFillColor(int);

    void setWindowVisibility(int);
    void setWindowXpos(int);
    void setWindowYpos(int);
    void setWindowWidth(int);
    void setWindowHeight(int);

    void setWaitTime(uint);
    void setParentMode(uint);
    void addParentMode(uint);
    void removeParentMode(uint);

    Jav::cstring toString();
    Jav::cstring getError() { return error; }

 private:
    Jav::cstring buildEnvironment();

 private:
    PROCESS_INFORMATION info = {};
    Jav::rFile m_read_end;
    Jav::rFile m_error_end;
    Jav::wFile m_write_end;
    OVERLAPPED async_struct;
    uint flags = 0;
    uint waitTime = INFINITE;
    Builder *builder;
    Jav::Error error = "";
}; 

Jav::cstring getEnvVar(const char *name);
Jav::cstring findExecutableAssociatedWithFileName(const char*);
Jav::cstring findExecutableAssociatedWithFileExtension(const char*);
```

I have implemented all functions except the asynchronous since I now understand how to use synchronous read and write. Basically you must know what the child function you are trying to connect to does. If you try to read the child process and it never ever writes to std out or std error, your parent process wont have anything to read and will deadlock.

I also now have a firm understanding of Pipes. A pipe is made up of two handles. one handle for writing and one handle for reading. By using the function CreatePipe, it will auto setup the writing handle and the reading handle. Registering these two handles as one pipe. A system buffer is created to store written data and is decremented when the reading handle reads. This is also how binders work in android.

**THE REAL PROBLEM**

All was going well until I put my Process class to the test and tried to run notepad. I added two path strings to its environment. By not passing a Null environment, the process doesnt inherit the system environment variables; and in the case of notepad it lead to note pad returning a error code, 0xc0150004.Obviously notepad requires certain System Environment variables.

How the heck do I allow the child process to inherit all System Variables and append my user environment strings to that?

Comment: Check out my short video tutorial on create process and use of pipes in windows.  https://youtu.be/v6I6tGvuw5c

Comment: @seccpur Thanks but you didnt answer my question. Check the last sentence of my essay to see what I really want to know.

Comment: Does it not work if you only keep the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @ssbssa I sincerely didnt understand your question. By it I guess you mean notepad. But which PATH environment variable do you refer? By the way I Remy Lebeau and GetEnvironmentStringsA(); parsed it and appended my custom environment. This works and notepad runs. However running codeblocks is slightly more complicated. I got codeblocks to open a cpp file, but it refuses to open a header file. Via my Process class.

Answer (score 2):

> How the heck do I allow the child process to inherit all System Variables and append my user environment strings to that?

The environment block you pass to `CreateProcess()` is what the new process receives, no more, no less. The new process inherits the existing environment block only when the `lpEnvironment` parameter is `NULL`.

MSDN demonstrates how to use `(Get|Set)EnvironmentVariable()` to let the new process inherit an environment block containing modified variables (but not appended variables):

[Changing Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/changing-environment-variables)

So, to do what you are asking, you will have to retrieve the calling process' existing environment block with [`GetEnvironmentStrings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentstrings), make a copy of it, append your custom variables to the copy as needed, pass the copy to `CreateProcess()`, and then free the copy.

Comment: Thank you very very very much for addressing my problem. The problem now is that ,Changing Environment Variables, which I read already only showed how to get single variables and you must know the variables off head. Solution 2: GetEnvironemntStringsA only returns a token string on my WinXp. '=::=::\'. Passing this string to CreateProcess also inherits System Environment. But appending to it fails. I mean I ensured that I kept the terminating null character and it still doesnt work. But your suggestion retrieve the variables is what I will try. There must be a enumeration function.

Comment: Alright I solved it. GetEnvironmentStrings returns the variables but I wasnt parsing it properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user13947194 There is no Win32 API function for enumerating environment variables. You have to use `GetEnvironmentStrings()` to get the entire block and then split the `name=value` pairs manually.

Comment: Yes sir Remy I did that as my last comment shows. I got notepad running. Now I must know, does CreateProcess use the child environment or the parent environment path variable when deducing the path of the app you are trying to run? I thought it would use the environment I passed to CreateProcess, but it seems to be using parent process environment.

Comment: @user13947194 it uses the parent's environment

Comment: Mr. Remy I have one question that is bothering me. CreateProcess uses neither the environment or current directory arguments passed to it, to deduce relative filepaths passed to it. Then why the heck does it ask for these arguments? It is confusing in regards to intent, and seems to make no sense.

Comment: @user13947194 the child process needs an environment to run in. It needs a working directory to start with. CreateProcess() provides the option to let the parent process decide whether to customize those values on the child's behalf as needed, or just default them as the OS sees fit. Why is that so confusing?

Comment: As I said the intent is confusing. Everybody would guess that those arguments would be used to deduce relative filepaths. Also I don't know why the process needs an environment. I never use it, except here where I was trying to use relative filepaths. And I dont know why I would ever want to set the current directory of a process. That seems pretty unsafe, and Android doesnt have that feature. Is this just antiquated Windows functionality, or did Microsoft have a relevant reason.

Comment: And as I spend more time trying to polish my Process class to simply work; I am trying to run codeblocks by passing it a filepath as its only argument but codeblocks will not run, and when it does it opens the same file every time. What I thought I understand is that, when you double click a file, the system passes the filename as an argument to the executable; but obviously it is more complicated than this. Note doing same with batch files don't work either.

Comment: @user13947194 "*Everybody would guess that those arguments would be used to deduce relative filepaths*" - or, they would not guess, and read the documentation for proper behavior. "*I don't know why the process needs an environment. I never use it*" - YOU might not, but you don't know what every possible child process will need. "*I dont know why I would ever want to set the current directory of a process*" - a child process may want to use its own relative paths, so they would have to be relative to something.

Comment: @user13947194 "*when you double click a file, the system passes the filename as an argument to the executable*" - if that is how the file type is setup to behave, yes. That is not always the case, though. File types have any different behaviors they can employ when invoked. They are not always passed to an app as a command-line parameter. "*obviously it is more complicated than this*" - OSes are complex systems.

Comment: lots of respect sir Remy. Love how you actually read and understand my questions. It seems I have to research the complex process of double click to open file.

Comment: @user13947194 see [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper), particularly the sections on how verbs and file associations work, and how file types are registered. Any further questions should be posted separately, as they don't relate to the CreateProcess question in this post.